# Cascade issue when deleting an entity in a one-to-one relationship using Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-one

I have the following db tables which I have simplified for this example:

**Webpage** Id, URLIdentifier

**WebpageMetaData** Webpage_id Keywords

Webpage_id is the primary key for the table and a foriegn key back to the webpage table.

I am then using Fluent NHibernate and its automapping feature to map these to the following POCO classes:

```
public class Webpage
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string UrlIdentifier { get; set; }
    public virtual WebpageMetaData WebpageMetaData { get; set; }
```

}

```
public class WebpageMetaData
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Keywords{ get; set; }
    public virtual Webpage Webpage { get; set; }
```

}

I want to map these entities as one-to-one, so I override the automapping as follows:

```
public class WebpageMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Webpage>
{        
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Webpage> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasOne(w => w.WebpageMetaData)
            .Not.Constrained()
            .Fetch.Join()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class WebpageMetaDataMap : IAutoMappingOverride<WebpageMetaData>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<WebpageMetaData> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Id(w => w.Id, "Webpage_id").GeneratedBy.Foreign("Webpage");

        mapping.HasOne(w => w.Webpage)
            .ForeignKey("Webpage_id")
            .Constrained()
            .Fetch.Join()
            .Cascade.None();
    }
}
```

I have tested these mappings and cascade rules and they work for selecting, inserting and updating.  However when i perform a delete of the WebpageMetaData I get an exception saying that

"deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)[WebpageMetaData#524]"

The only way to stop the exception is by doing the following before saving:

```
webpageMetaData.Webpage.WebpageMetaData = null;
```

So I have to set a null reference to myself from my parent??!  This seems wrong?  have I got my mapping wrong?

Thanks.

**Update 1:**
Please see the NH mappings that FLuent is producing, in case this is of help to the hard core NHibernator's :)

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-access="property" auto-import="true" default-cascade="none" default-lazy="true">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="EveryPage.Core.Domain.Webpage, EveryPage.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="`Webpage`">
    <id name="Id" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" unsaved-value="0">
      <column name="Id" />
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <one-to-one cascade="all" class="EveryPage.Core.Domain.WebpageMetaData, EveryPage.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" constrained="false" fetch="join" name="WebpageMetaData" />
    <property name="UrlIdentifier" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="UrlIdentifier" />
    </property>    
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-access="property" auto-import="true" default-cascade="none" default-lazy="true">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="EveryPage.Core.Domain.WebpageMetaData, EveryPage.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="`WebpageMetaData`">
    <id name="Id" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" unsaved-value="0">
      <column name="Webpage_id" />
      <generator class="foreign">
        <param name="property">Webpage</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <one-to-one cascade="none" class="EveryPage.Core.Domain.Webpage, EveryPage.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" constrained="true" fetch="join" foreign-key="Webpage_id" name="Webpage" />
    <property name="Keywords" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Keywords" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your mapping isn't quite right. If you take a look at the [NH documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone), their example of using one-to-one for a parent-child relationship involves a many-to-one mapping (with unique=true) and a one-to-one mapping, not a pair of one-to-one mappings. (A pair of one-to-one mappings is for the case where two tables are associated using a shared PK)

I suggest you try changing your mapping to better match the example to see if that fixes the cascades.

Comment: Thanks for your help Paul.
However my two tables do share the same PK, this is the design I am after.  So I am trying to use a pair of one-to-one mappings.  However the cascade is not playing how I would have thought?!

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. I can now see how your WebpageMetaDataMap has the same column name for the ID and the relationship. I can't see anything wrong with your mapping then. You might want to examine the XML that FNH is generating and then ask on the nhusers mailing list about how one-to-one cascades are supposed to work. Sorry I wasn't much help.

Comment: Hi Paul, no problem, its good just to have someone else tell you that you haven't done anything obviously wrong, especially when your new to a technology!
How do I get to the XML that FNH is creating for my mappings?
Thanks

Comment: Use the ExportTo method demonstrated on the bottom of this wiki page:
http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_configuration

Answer (score 0):

Hm, Cascade-all-delete-orphan maybe?

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I don't think delete orphan is an option with a one-to-one mapping, I think they apply to parent-child relationships?  You cannot get an orphan in this type of relation, a WebpageMetaData cannot exist without a Webpage.

Comment: one-to-one cascade all-delete-orphan is now supported and working in NHibernate 4.1. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44026508/379279) can help you to use it with fluent nhibernate.